# Php Calling the functions of same class one after another

Tags: php

I want to write something like (laravel uses):

```
View::make('FooBarView')->with('foo', $foo)
                        ->with('bar', $bar);
```

My knowledge and imagination made me to use new self instances. But I don't think that this is the best idea around and I could not handle it.

Google couldn't help me because of my bad keywords I think. I don't want to make you write code for me for sure but what is the name of this design pattern or whatever?

In laravel's source, with function uses

```
return $this;
```

But how to use it after make?

*By the way, in this example; with method helps you to set variables for view's render.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To call what the function returns, the function will have to return something that is possible to call.

In this case, you could for example return "this":

```
class View {
  /** 
  * @returns View
  */
  public static function make($foo) { 
    /* do stuff, return new View instance */ 
    return new View();
  }
  /** 
  * @returns View
  */
  public function with($foo, $bar){
    /* do stuff */
    return $this;
  }
}
```

That way, whenever you call `with` you will get the class instance back, which in turn will be callable:

```
 View::make("foo")->with("foo")->with("bar");
 // Will be same as:
 $v = View::make("foo");
 $v = $v->with("foo");
 $v = $v->with("bar");
```

Comment: To mention is that Laravel doesn't do it this way. The View::make() is just a static Facade. Actually you call the object: `$app->make('view')->make()` So you don't call a factory method in Laravel. However your approach is the best way to get started :D